# Why does relocating the running exe makes it stop?

Tags: python, windows, exe

Basically I convert this python file to an executable with PyInstaller.
But relocating the path of the exe from within, makes it stop from running.
Re-running the executable from that relocated path doesn't cause any errors, and works just fine.

Looping the main function using while True keeps it running, but fails to establish any connection with the server. (done in the Agent class)

This is a part of the python file that gets converted to exe

```
def main():

    try:
        # try to relocate file (always works)
        root_path = os.environ["HOMEPATH"]
        file_name = os.path.basename(sys.executable)

        current_path = os.path.realpath(sys.executable)[2:]

        path_needed = os.path.join(root_path, file_name)

        if current_path != path_needed:
            print(str(current_path) + " != " + str(path_needed))
            os.rename(current_path, path_needed)

    except Exception as e:
        print("main exception with exception " + str(e))


    agent = Agent()
    agent.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # while True:
    main()
```

Comment: Please explain why you downvote the question.

Comment: (Did not downvote) Your question is about how (your) operating system works, not about programming. Sounds like Windows BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. @KlausD.

Comment: The working drive from the working directory may not be the same as the executable path. We have no control over the initial working directory. That's set by whoever executes the program. So the subsequent `rename` call may fail. Additionally, it could be a UNC or device path that starts with "\\server\share" or "\\?\", so trimming the first 2 characters is generally invalid.

Comment: A user's home directory is `"%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"`. Don't assume the home drive is "C:". Better yet, don't use this variable combination. It's unreliable. In some contexts such as running via runas.exe or Task Scheduler, it ends up set to "%SystemRoot%\System32". The profile directory `"%USERPROFILE%"` is reliable, and it's the default home directory if one isn't explicitly set for the user. At least fall back on the profile directory if the home directory is the "System32" directory.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and clear explanation! @eryksun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by calling the exe file again (and just allow the current one to close out)

```
if current_path != path_needed:
        print(str(current_path) + " != " + str(path_needed))
        os.rename(current_path, path_needed)
        try:
            os.startfile("C:\\" + path_needed)
        except Exception as exception:
            print("main execute exception with exception " + str(exception))                
        return
```

Comment: The caller that executes your program may be waiting on it and checking the exit code. You could use something like `sys.exit(subprocess.call(path_needed))`, so you can wait on the new instance and proxy the exit code. Better yet, figure out why PyInstaller's frozen-executable launcher is exiting when you relocate the unpacked executable. Apparently it's watching the unpacked executable file or watching the temp directory where it unpacks it, and exiting if it thinks the file was removed. Maybe it's part of some implicit cleanup strategy.